# Elementwise multiplication for indexedbase symbols in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Consider the following sample code

```
import sympy as s
U      = s.IndexedBase('U')
V      = s.IndexedBase('V')
x      = s.Idx('x', N)
```

Is there a way to multiply `U` and `V` so that the result is still indexedbase (i.e., what I would like is `myProduct(U,V)[x] = U[x]*V[x]`)? I tried `(U*V)[x]` to no success (it returns the error `'Mul' object is not scriptable`. I also looked at making `U,V` matrices and applying the Hadamard product, i.e.

```
import sympy as s
N = 10
U      = s.MatrixSymbol('U',1,N)
V      = s.MatrixSymbol('V',1,N)
x      = s.Idx('x', N)
s.HadamardProduct(U,V)[0,x]
```

but in this I case, I would always have to write an extra `0` to indicate the (only) row index, e.g., `s.HadamardProduct(U,V)[0,x]` which is kind of cumbersome.

Comment: Imagine for the moment that I don't have a `sympy` session running (nor the sympy docs).  Fill in the blanks for us.  What do you mean by "no success"?  Error?  wrong result?  Elaborate on the parameter to `HadamardProduct`.  What's wrong with the extra 0?

Comment: I tried a copy-n-paste, and got a NameError.  Turns out the correct name is `s.IndexedBase`.  I'm going to vote close because of `not reproducable/typo!

Comment: I'm not sure what `U*V` is expected to mean here

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from sympy import IndexedBase
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> IndexedBase("U")[x]*IndexedBase("V")[x]
U[x]*V[x]
```

Do you really need to call it a special way as in `myProd(U,V)[x]` or does the above work for you?